# iPhone, to summarise updates, what do I need to be aware of with OS 4 phones?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm developing a new app, I haven't previously written an app which will cater for OS 4 phones.

I know theres now multi tasking, so I have to cater for apps resuming, but I'm not sure how?

Also theres retina graphics, I'm not sure if its best to resize my own x2 images or let the phone do it?

Also, it seems that the iphone 4's are more square, so I'm not sure what I to cater for 4 and 3 etc ?

I could do with someone whose been through the process to advice me about these topics and to point out any other things which I should be aware of.

I realise that there will be documentation on this, which I'd be glad to read when I have the chance, but I'd be grateful for a summary and experience tackling these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provide all of these in the dev center!

Login required....

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/index.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html